# Function or package or method of inputting a series of points or segments determining when a new area has been closed off

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to take gcode for a wire edm machine that is cutting many identical shapes out of a thin disk. It cuts orthogonal to the plane of movement with its path defined by a list of xy coordinates. I’ve started by parsing the gcode to be able to isolate the xy coordinates and then used sympy to create a list of points in a list.

My end goal is to have the program able to identify the point at which each new loop is closed. Every time this happens there is no longer anything supporting the piece and it will fall free. I want to be able to identify this point and then interpolate a certain small distance away from that point along the path of travel that will change how the machine is cutting at that moment. By visual inspection it is easy to see where these points lie, but the more I delve into this project it seems to get harder and harder. One place that I’ve started is by creating polygons out of the points with the same number of sides as the pieces I’m cutting out and then comparing the calculated area against my own calculated area knowing the size of the tip.

Once these are equal I know I have found the first section of code that is enclosing a piece and can identify the endpoint. From here it becomes difficult. If I have enclosed a triangle now I only need two segments to have another tip fall out as I can bring the cut back to area that is already removed. Once I’ve run out of space though I need to make transfer movements and on my new line it will take three segments to free a piece again.

Ideally there would be a way to define uncut space and previously cut space. Possibly by constantly adding to a list of points that define a polygon of cut area. I’m lost. I need a fresh brain or maybe just to talk it out with someone. Any assistance or questions or ideas or anything would be greatly appreciated. This is a passion project that I have taken on and is also my second python program ever and I am deep over my head in murky water.

Here is the source gcode that I am parsing points from:
O5708
(804 TIPS IN-7419)
(0,0 CENTER OF DISC)
(ENABLE M01)
N0015 G90
N0020 M15 P0
N0025 G92 X1.9 Y.3
N0030 G50 G41 G01 X1.5
N0035 X1.3652 Y.312
N0040 X1.2722 Y.3901
N0045 Y.234
M01
N0050 X1.3652 Y.312
N0055 Y.156
N0060 X1.2722 Y.234
N0065 Y.078
N0070 X1.3652 Y.156
N0075 Y0
N0080 X1.2722 Y.078
N0085 Y-.078

…………..
It is much much longer than this. Thousands of lines, but perhaps you get the idea.

```
from sympy import *
from math import *
xy = ""
points = ""
count = 0
index = 0
indexprint = ""
import pyperclip

with open ('WIRE.txt', 'rt') as myfile:  # Open file lorem.txt for reading text
    mytext = myfile.read()   

mywords = mytext.split()
sides = 3

for word in mywords :
    if word[0] == 'X' or word[0] == 'Y':
        xy = xy + "\n" + word
    index +=1    
xy = xy.split()



for coordinate in xy:
    if coordinate[0] == 'X':
        lastxcoord = coordinate
    else:
        lastycoord = coordinate

    if xy[count][0] == xy[count - 1][0] and xy[count][0] == 'X':
        xy.insert(count, lastycoord)
    if xy[count][0] == xy[count - 1][0] and xy[count][0] == 'Y':
        xy.insert(count, lastxcoord)
    count += 1
count2 = 0


count2 +=1
for i in xy:   
    if count2 % 2 == 0:
        points = points + ' ' + i[1:] + '\n'
    elif count2 % 2 == 1:
        points = points + i[1:]
    count2 += 1



pyperclip.copy(points)
count2 = 0

for i in xy:
    i = i[1:]
    xy[count2] = i
    count2 += 1
tip = 0
i = 0


points2d = []
while i < 200:     #(len(xy) // 2)
    points2d.append(Point(xy[i],xy[i+1]))
    i += 2
    print('working')
i = 0

found = 0
firstpoly = 'no first poly yet'
while i < 70:
    s = tuple(points2d[i:i+sides])
    poly = Polygon(*s)



    try:
        if ((.00725865 - abs(poly.area)) < .0001) and ((.00725865 - abs(poly.area)) > -.0001) and (found != 1):
                placeh = tuple(points2d[i:i+sides])
                firstpoly = Polygon(*placeh)
                found = 1
                #print(poly)
                continue
    except:
        print('')
    '''    
    try:    
        print(poly.intersection(firstpoly))
    except:
        print('no intersection')
    '''

    i += 1
    #print(poly.sides[2])
    try:
        if firstpoly.sides[2] == firstpoly.intersection(poly):
            print('aha')

    except:
        print('okie')
```

Thank you,

Shane